# Do GitHub's statistics of visitors and cloners include owners?

Tags: github, statistics

GitHub's UI offers a graph of (unique) visitors and cloners. Question is, does that include visits and clones by yourself, as an owner of a project? If not - what about visits and clones by recognized contributors?

Answer (score 1):

It definitely seems to include owner visits in the graph. I have a GitHub repo that I just started last week and is very small, with almost non-existent web traffic. I visited it today, and the graph went from 0 unique visitors to 1.  Similarly, on a day last week when I worked on the project, the graph shows 1 unique visitor (as compared to 0 for most of the rest of the week).